# Jenkins fails to run test with Maven and Java 21

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to run `mvn test` in Jenkins when code is pushed to git repo.

When I build tests in Jenkins, it gives me this:

```
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 41593
[Java App] $ java -cp /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.14.jar:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven /var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3206.vb_15dcf73f6a_9.jar /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.14.jar /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.14.jar 41593
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Java App/pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< org.example:javaProject >-----------------------
[INFO] Building javaProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ javaProject ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Java App/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Java App/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ javaProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files with javac [debug release 21] to target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.680 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-04T09:52:19Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project javaProject: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Java App/pom.xml to org.example/javaProject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/javaProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>javaapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>21</release>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It looks like it doesn't support Java 21 (why?).

---

I tried adding JDK installation (the directory exists) [image]

And when I run `readlink -f $(which java)`, the path is correct (I only excluded the `/bin/java` part). Output:

```
konstantin@konstantin-ThinkPad-T490:/etc/init.d$ readlink -f $(which java)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

And now Jenkins says this:

```
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 44223
[Java App] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.14.jar:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven /var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3206.vb_15dcf73f6a_9.jar /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.14.jar /var/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.14.jar 44223
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Java App"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:994)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:282)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:237)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:802)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1895)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: The error message tells that the setup for the build job is not correct and not correctly defining JDK 21 for the build you are expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your workspace name has a whitespace (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Java App). Maybe you could try renaming your workspace so that it doesn't have a whitespace or check the places where your workspace is used and surround it with double quotes.

Additionally, you might want to check whether the directories you are using exist in the filesystem. It is also recommended to check the filesystem permissions and whether the user with whom your pipeline is executed (e.g. jenkins) has the correct access permissions to the filesystem directories you are using.